# Authentication with Facebook (PHP SDK) and Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

Alright, so for a couple days now I have been trying to integrate Facebook authentication into my Codeigniter based website. I have included the Facebook PHP SDK as a library and that seems to connect just fine, however when I use the getUser method in the SDK a 0 is returned indicating that I am not logged in (except that I am logged in to facebook). Below I have included the PHP SDK in library form, the model that calls the methods in the SDK, the controller that captures data from the model, and the view that displays the information to the user. I hope that yall can offer me some insite in to this aggravating issue. Thanks for all your help in advance!! (and just incase yall are wondering I am using some code from a tutorial I found on http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/) :

FB PHP SDK library (stored in application/libraries):

```
<?php //if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require_once "base_facebook.php";

/**
 * Extends the BaseFacebook class with the intent of using
 * PHP sessions to store user ids and access tokens.
 */
class Facebook extends BaseFacebook
{
  /**
   * Identical to the parent constructor, except that
   * we start a PHP session to store the user ID and
   * access token if during the course of execution
   * we discover them.
   *
   * @param Array $config the application configuration.
   * @see BaseFacebook::__construct in facebook.php
   */
  public function __construct($config) {
    if (!session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
  }

  protected static $kSupportedKeys =
    array('state', 'code', 'access_token', 'user_id');

  /**
   * Provides the implementations of the inherited abstract
   * methods.  The implementation uses PHP sessions to maintain
   * a store for authorization codes, user ids, CSRF states, and
   * access tokens.
   */
  protected function setPersistentData($key, $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to setPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    $_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;
  }

  protected function getPersistentData($key, $default = false) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to getPersistentData.');
      return $default;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]) ?
      $_SESSION[$session_var_name] : $default;
  }

  protected function clearPersistentData($key) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to clearPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    unset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]);
  }

  protected function clearAllPersistentData() {
    foreach (self::$kSupportedKeys as $key) {
      $this->clearPersistentData($key);
    }
  }

  protected function constructSessionVariableName($key) {
    return implode('_', array('fb',
                              $this->getAppId(),
                              $key));
  }
}
?>
```

The Model:

```
<?php

/*
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */


class Facebook_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $profile = null;
        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $config = array(
                        'appId'  => 'MYAPPID',
                        'secret' => 'MYSECRET',
                        'fileUpload' => true, // Indicates if the CURL based @ syntax for file uploads is enabled.
                    );

        echo $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

        // Get User ID
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
        //
        // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
        // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
        // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

        $profile = null;
        if($user)
        {
            try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }


        $fb_data = array(
                        'me' => $profile,
                        'uid' => $user,
                        'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                            array(
                                'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream', // app permissions
                                'redirect_uri' => '/profile' // URL where you want to redirect your users after a successful login
                            )
                        ),
                        'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                    );

         $this->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);

    }

}

?>
```

The Controller:

```
<?php

    class The_facebook extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('facebook_model');
        }

        public function index(){
            print_r($this->facebook);
            $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data'); // This array contains all the user FB information

            if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me']))
            {
                // If this is a protected section that needs user authentication
                // you can redirect the user somewhere else
                // or take any other action you need
                //redirect(base_url());
                echo "redirect";    

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array(
                        'fb_data' => $fb_data,
                      );

                $this->load->view('sand_view', $data);
            }

        }

    }

?>
```

And finally the view:

```
<body>
<div>
  <?php if(!$fb_data['me']): ?>
  Please login with your FB account: <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['loginUrl']; ?>">login</a>
  <!-- Or you can use XFBML -->
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="100" data-max-rows="1" data-scope="email,user_birthday,publish_stream"></div>
  <?php else: ?>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb_data['uid']; ?>/picture" alt="" class="pic" />
  <p>Hi <?php echo $fb_data['me']['name']; ?>,<br />
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('topsecret'); ?>">You can access the top secret page</a> or <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['logoutUrl']; ?>">logout</a> </p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Facebook PHP-SDK 3.x to register/login user with Codeigniter 2.1.0](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9454238/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-x-to-register-login-user-with-codeigniter-2-1-0)

Comment: I don't believe so, his implementation does not work where mine does except that it can't identify a logged in user

Comment: My implementation **does** work. BTW, `does not work` is not helpful!

Comment: is cookie_domain defined properly in application/config/config.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an integration of my own, you can download it here from GitHub:
https://github.com/cworsley4/Codeigniter-with-Facebook

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my hack to it was that I added the config array to the constructor of the facebook class instead of passing it as a parameter to the constructor. For some reason the config array wasn't being passed or read.

so my hack looks as follows:

```
    public function __construct() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }


    $config = array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET
    );

    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with the Facebook SDK on CodeIgniter a while now, and decided to release my code as an open source extension.
There's one thing: this code uses the SDK as a library, and has built a model on top of it, having multiple other awesome functions ready to be used.

In case you'd like to use it, or contribute in any way (issues, commits, etc), feel free to join:

https://github.com/AlphabaseIT/CIconnect