# Integrate facebook sdk5 to codeigniter manually

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

What are the difference from facebook-php-sdk v3 to v5. 
How can integrate the lastest facebook php sdk 5 to codeigniter v3?

I am looking for a way to set it up manually. I did a round of searching and could only find documentation on sdk 3. I am new to codeigniter and i want to implement a way to use Facebook to login and validate user throughout the website. I have installed codeigniter in a subfolder and made changes in .htacess to remove index.php from urls.

I am sorry, I don't have much but been searching online and couldn't find much on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication with Facebook (PHP SDK) and Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810691/authentication-with-facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter)

Comment: Hi, the question is for the latest sdk, which i feel have changed significantly from the earlier versions. I feel the suggested post deals with old one.

Comment: Also i am not able to run composer, i am trying on my hosted website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to pull it off finally.
I installed Xampp in my windows laptop, copied the files from my hosted server to a folder with in htdocs folder of XAMPP ( yeah should have started from here to begin with :) )

Steps followed

1. Install a recent version of XAMPP
2. move your website files including codeigniter installation to htdocs folder or a sub-folder within htdocs
3. Install exe file for composer from https://getcomposer.org/
4. copy files and Follow step by step at instruction https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter

The Steps mentioned there are given below for a quick glance. [

1.Download the library files and add the files to your CodeIgniter installation. Only the library, config and composer.json files are required.

2.In your CodeIgniter /application/config/config.php file, set $config['composer_autoload'] to TRUE.

3. In your CodeIgniter /application/config/config.php file, configure the Session Variables section. ( just make session autoload)

4.Update the facebook.php config file in /application/config/facebook.php with your Facebook App details.

5.Install the Facebook PHP SDK by navigating to your applications folder in the terminal and run Composer with composer install.

6.Autoload the library in application/config/autoload.php or load it in needed controllers with $this->load->library('facebook');.

]
Just keep in mind that the composer.json mentioned in steps and one to be run is with in the "application" folder ( one that comes with codeigniter). So you should run the composer after you reach to this folder in cmd.

Also auto loading url helper might make things easier for you.
You can now migrate the code to your hosted server. :)